# check checkbox inside div if name begin with some string

Tags: jquery

I'm adding a `<div>` element which contains a `<input type="checkbox">` using jQuery, then I have another `<input type="text">`, what I need is to check if any of checkboxes names inside my `<div>` element begin with the value I'm writing inside the `<input type="text">`?

Comment: A **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)** would be helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example.  The event fires with every key press, so you may want to change that to another event, such as blur, or enhance the function so that it looks for the user to press enter.  Or, add a button and trigger the event on the button click.

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#textInputID').on('keyup', function() {
        var inputName = $(this).val();
        if($.trim(inputName) !== "") {
            $('#myDiv input[name=' + inputName + ']').prop('checked', true);
        }
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
   <input id="textInputID" type="text" >
   <input type="checkbox" name="test1" >
   <input type="checkbox" name="test1" >
</div>
```